# How do I create default bookmarks in Firefox 17 ESR

Tags: firefox, bookmarks, firefox-profile

I've started with an installation of Firefox 17.0.6 ESR on 64Bit Windows 7 and set the bookmarks bar the way I want.

I've used the 'Export Bookmarks to HTML' option and stored the file as 'bookmarks.html' in the c:\program files(x86)\Mozilla Firefox\default\preferences folder

When I create a new user on the machine, that user just gets the default 'Most Visited' and 'Getting Started' links.

I'd prefer not to have to use the CCK as I've had some issues with it in the past for upgrades.

If it was possible to ALSO have the bookmark bar shown on startup for new user, that would be extra awesome.

Thanks all,
Chris

Answer (score 1):

Found it in a deployed version of last year's software load.

The bookmarks.html file goes in /default/profile

Not in /pref or /preferences (as suggested by http://mike.kaply.com/2012/10/15/get-ready-for-the-firefox-17-esr/)

Answer (score 0):

Ahhh, mate, I'd suggest upgrading to Firefox 20.1, but that's your own thing.

On to your answer:

1) Click the firefox button in the top right corner

2) Hover over bookmarks and select 'Show All Bookmarks'

3) An option in the menu bar should be 'Import and back up', select that one.

4) Mash that 'Import bookmarks from HTML' and locate your file

5) Boom, done.

An little note: Xmarks automatically syncs bookmarks for you across accounts/machines via an addon, which can be found here if you'd like it: http://www.xmarks.com/ Don't mind that LastPass stuff, it's a free add-on that can be extended with a few paid features(Which I find worthless)

Comment: Exiled - Thanks for the suggestions for getting the bookmarks in and the upgrade to 21 -- I'm looking to have this done for the 'default' user so that when new user accounts are created, they all get the bookmarks. As for 17ESR vs (anything higher than that), we're at an institution where we want security updates, but not other updates that would potentially break our webapps. Thanks.